# Grouping data based on Hours

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-time

I have a list of Object which contain a field generation time, in which I am storing time in long format by `System.currentTimeInMills()` function. Data is look like below:

```
List<MyObject> myObj = Arrays.asList(
    new MyObject(time="1561473186140", name="123", status=200)
    new MyObject(time="1561473186123", name="ABC", status=200)
    new MyObject(time="1561473183435", name="ABC", status=200)
    new MyObject(time="1561473185666", name="123", status=200)
    new MyObject(time="1561473186132", name="ABC", status=200)
    new MyObject(time="1561473183423", name="ABC", status=200)
    new MyObject(time="1561473184242", name="123", status=200)
    new MyObject(time="1561473186190", name="ABC", status=200)
    new MyObject(time="1561473186098", name="ABC", status=200)
);
```

Now I have to group the data based on hour bases. Like from 10AM-11AM how many objects are there, like 11AM-12PM etc. So how can I achieve it using Java 8 Stream API.

Comment: Do you want to group or filter data in a new list?

Comment: Give it a try. Create a utility that identifies a given time into a key range such as `10AM-11AM`, then using `for` loop try and use that util while you put the elements into a `Map` and count the values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> Instant.ofEpochMilli(o.getTime())
                .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getHour()));

result.forEach((hour, objects) -> 
        System.out.println(hour + " - " + (hour + 1) + ": " + objects));
```

This uses the Java Time API to get the hours of that timestamp. Change the time zone to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want group of objects grouped by hour:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> result = myObj.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(o.getTimestamp()), ZoneId.systemDefault()).getHour()));
```

---

If you need only the number of objects, not the objects themselves:

```
myObj.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(o.getTimestamp()), ZoneId.systemDefault()).getHour(), Collectors.counting()));
```